# Magento 2 curl send header with response

Tags: magento2, curl

I call Curl in my code. Please have a look

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function __construct(

            \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl $httpAdapter
) {
    $this->_httpAdapter = $httpAdapter;
}
    public function createBookingNumber($service,$order)
            {
 $config = array('timeout' => 60);
 $this->_httpAdapter->setConfig($config);
    $this->_httpAdapter->addOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $this->_httpAdapter->addOption(CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    $this->_httpAdapter->addOption(CURLOPT_POST,1);
$this->_httpAdapter->write(\Zend_Http_Client::POST, 'myapi url', '1.1',array("Authorization: Basic cm9iaW5sYXVAcG9zdG5ldC5jb20uYXU6TWFnaWNtYW4yMTEwNzU=",
  "Content-Type: application/json"), json_encode($data));  // $data is an array which I need to convert in jeson and send.

    $response = $this->_httpAdapter->read();
    print_r($response);
    $this->_httpAdapter->close(); 
}

}
```

But when I print my response I am getting header too, but I set false in my code.

My Response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OKDate: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 10:42:04 GMTServer: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)Vary: Authorization,Accept-EncodingX-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17Cache-Control: no-cacheSet-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjFxQ05ZZUpIQVFUWU4wWU9ZaW16cHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaVFCZVhwZ01HN3laUDhwSGFcL0Z6Z1lsOTd6VUxsXC93REFiXC8yMThlRVk1cklRUmQxVmlYaGlibjdVU25rNkxMY3BHTmJWVTJrazl6YVwvMnJOWTZYaHJBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3ZWZjYmU3ZTZkMmJhMWVkOWE4OTFmMzliMTNhZDg2ZjE5ODE5NzE3NDNlN2U2MzkyZDBmM2Q2YjcwOTE0MGJhIn0=; expires=Tue, 10-Jan-2017 12:42:12 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/Set-Cookie: laravel_session=236088dea752bc581c762a9448febf1eb085fc2c; expires=Tue, 10-Jan-2017 12:42:12 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponlyTransfer-Encoding: chunkedContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8.{"status":"ok","response":{"user_id":17,"vendor":"dhlcp","description":"","tracking_no":"CPWEXPD000000131","label_pdf":"JVBERi0xLjQKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL01lZGlhQm94IFswIDAgNDIwLjAwIDU5NS4wMF0KL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFI+
```

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add header = '' in your config variable......

```
public function createBookingNumber($service,$order)
 {
 $config = array('timeout' => 60,'header'=>'');
 $this->_httpAdapter->setConfig($config);
```